# Android sqlite Where clause returning one row column with id

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

I want to get a single column of a row with an id , shall I do

```
 String selQ = "SELECT " + name + " FROM " + table+ " WHERE " + id+ " = '" + id + "'";
```

or

```
 String selQ = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + id+ " = '" + id + "'";
```

Shall I get a cursor?

Comment: Don't just concatenate your variables with SQL strings. You'll make your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Why `"WHERE " + id + " =  '" + id + "'"`? Isn't the name of the ID column always just "id" or something? Don't you mean something like `"WHERE id='" + id + "'"`? (I'd look into using prepared statements as the other comment suggested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use query() method

```
private Cursor getSingleRow(int id){    
    Cursor cur = db.query(TABLE, null,
                 "_id= ?", new String[] { "" + id }, null,
                null, null);
        if (cur != null) {
            cur.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cur;
}
```

or you can execute row query just like what you have proposed with some errors removed

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * from " + TABLE_NAME
            + "WHERE _id="+id , null);
```

Comment: And when I get the cursor how I get the String value from X column?

Comment: you can get values from the cursor based on the column index. e.g String value =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName))

Comment: how we can use the query method for search multi condition? for example "id=?" and name="?"

Answer (score 0):

* means all the columns in the table, if you only want the name you need to specify.
You can use the rawQuery() function once you made your string.